# Simulator menu cannot be opened

Tags: codenameone

I cannot use the menu in the simulator anymore. Clicking on them doesn't do anything.

I am using Netbeans 8.2 with CN1 5.0 on Windows 10.

I noticed this after i installed CN1 on IntelliJ to test it there.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem again on a Windows 10 machine. I am using Eclipse 2018-12. Today, I have installed Java 1.8.0_201 (previously I was using Java 1.8.0_192) and seen that menu items on Simulator are not working. I have reverted back to 1.8.0_192, but still menu items are not working.

So now I am thinking it is not related to Java release I use. Maybe a recent Windows Update messed things up?

I have also re-installed CN1 plugin and tried "Update Project Libs" from the "Basic CN1 Preferences". Still no progress...

I have seen that the same problem has also been reported today here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1398468/codename-one-simulator-menu-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

This was a regression in the Windows/Linux versions of the simulator. This didn't happen on Mac since menus work differently on Mac OS which is why we missed it. It doesn't happen in unit tests since unit tests check the functionality directly and not the menu.

We pushed out an update which you can get right now by opening `Codename One Settings` -> `Basic` -> `Update Project Libs`